# Javascript in iFrame document - how to fetch the browser address bar location?

Tags: javascript

I am encouraging people to embed my website on their own using an iFrame. What I need to do is to let the Javascript on my page find out their domain. So if they embed my page on http://yahoo.com then I need to be able to fetch that address.

How to?

I tried various things such as parent.window.location, window.location etc. But all I get is the address to my page in the iFrame.

Comment: I have no 100% certainty, but I think cross-domain policy works both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.parent.document.location` would give you the url

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
window.opener.document.location
```

or

```
window.parent.document.location
```